# google sheets script missing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've created a Google sheet and tried to add functions. I can create functions in the Script Editor, and they're visible, editable and run fine there. I've even added a couple of Google examples to make sure it's not my bad code.

However, in the sheet, the functions do not appear in autocomplete, nor do they work when typed out by hand. They do not appear in Add-On Manager, which has the "Manage add-ons" item greyed out. I can install and remove addons from the chrome store, but cannot see or use the functions I've created. How do I get these working on the sheet?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Did you add the [JSdoc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete)?

Comment: Well I used the sample code from Google that can be found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros

Comment: And this is fine in the Script Editor, but is nowhere to be seen in "Add-ons" or as a function in the sheet. I'm not sure what you mean about adding the JSDoc? Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to autocomplete you need to add the JSdoc string that I linked, for the menu you'll need to add a menu

Comment: Understood, Robin, thanks - but that's not the problem. It's not just the autocomplete, it's like the whole function is invisible to the sheet. Adding the JSDoc doesn't do anything, and nor does the function work when type the whole thing out manually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, your custom function will not appear in autocomplete but it will work!

[image]
[image]

To add it as an "Add-on" you must first publish it as one. You can use this example to add a menu to the menu bar

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Generate step-by-step...', functionName: 'generateStepByStep_'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Directions', menuItems);
}
```

However you need to make sure that the data is collected by the function or the user is prompted for data input

[image]